# TFS Build agent throws "unauthorized" exception

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

We have upgraded our TFS 2013 server to TFS 2015 and we are setting up the new build agents.

Prior to this we performed a trial run and got everything working reasonably well before we did the final conversion of our existing TFS database. The build agent worked perfectly fine.

To our surprise, our build agent no longer co-operates post-upgrade. Creating a trivial build definition and assigning it to the default queue results in an error being raised after 10-15 seconds.

We have tried re-deploying the build agent, play around with permissions and users, but to no avail.

All we get is this in the _diag\ logs:

```
11:18:09.699993 JobManager.StartJob(job.JobId = a9702f31-2dff-4057-8253-a32ebc106f32)
11:18:09.699993 JobInfo.ctor
11:18:09.699993 JobInfo.ctor - leave
11:18:09.699993 JobManager.StartJob - calling JobWriter.StartJob
11:18:09.699993 JobWriter.StartJob - enter
11:18:09.699993 JobWriter.StartJob - (SKIPPING)first renew
11:18:09.715619 JobWriter.StartJob - start continual renewing
11:18:09.715619 AuthorizationType : OAuth
11:18:09.731245 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:18:09.731245 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Unauthorized
11:18:09.731245    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
11:18:09.731245    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__79.MoveNext()
11:18:09.731245 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__76`1.MoveNext()
11:18:09.731245 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
11:18:09.731245 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssServerDataProvider.<ConnectAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
11:18:09.731245 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Common.ConnectionHelper.GetConnection(Uri serverUri, VssCredentials credentials)
11:18:09.731245    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.JobWriter.StartJob()
11:18:09.731245    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
11:18:09.731245    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__79.MoveNext()
11:18:09.731245 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__76`1.MoveNext()
11:18:09.731245 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
11:18:09.731245 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssServerDataProvider.<ConnectAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
11:18:09.731245 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
11:18:09.731245    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Common.ConnectionHelper.GetConnection(Uri serverUri, VssCredentials credentials)
11:18:09.731245    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.JobWriter.StartJob()
11:18:09.731245 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Running interactively or as a service makes no difference. I have enlisted the build agent's service user as a member of the 'Agent Pool Service Accounts' role.

I believe this is the offending request:

```
GET https://tfs:8443/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=IncludeServices&lastChangeId=-1&lastChangeId64=-1 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: VSServices/14.102.25423.0 (VsoAgent.exe) VsoAgent.exe/1.95.3
Accept-Language: en-US, nb-NO
X-TFS-FedAuthRedirect: Suppress
X-TFS-Session: 7a2e6368-a564-4231-bbd6-xxxxxxxxxx
X-VSS-Agent: VSS: b5d9c453-017f-407c-ac00-b479d0d0e8ed
Authorization: [huge bytesequence]
Host: tfs:8443
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

This is rewarded with a 401. My own adminuser however is able to load this URI just fine.

My own admin user is the one I used when I set up the agent. I have also tried launching vsoagent.exe interactively from this user... But no go. Reading between the lines (and looking at some of the roles) there is a user that bares the name of the machine that the agent runs on. I guess this user was created at first and is the one that is actually used. How do I get this situation under control?

**EDIT:** If I run vsoagent.exe interactively from a user that is NOT included in the pool's list of "Agent Pool Service Accounts", then the agent immediately errs out with `Access denied. admrunem needs Listen permissions for pool Regular to perform the action. For more information, contact the Team Foundation Server administrator.`. Adding admrunem to the list gets me a little further, namely to the error message that I am trying to diagnose (The "unauthorized" exception). Note: It uses NTLM authorization at this point, then for the fatal call seems to switch to OAUTH.

Answer (score 3):

Check that "Windows authentication" is enabled on Team Foundation Server IIS website. That fixed the issue for us.

[image]

Comment: yes!  Thanks for sharing.  That did the trick for us as well.  Will update some other threads I've seen on issue to hopefully point people in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the account that the agent is run under is in the "Agent Pool Service Account" role.
   [image]
2. Make sure the queue is provisioned in the collection ( https://your-tfs-server:8080/tfs/your-collection/_admin/_AgentQueue ). If not - select "New queue.." and select the existing queue.
3. Make sure you deploy the Windows build agent by exactly following [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/agents/windows).
4. Try to change a domain account which is a member of the Build Agent Service Accounts group and belongs to "Agent Pool Service Account" role, to see whether the agent would work or not.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you mean by "try to change a domain account". You mean run vsoagent as a different domain user? vsoagent /login:user,password? If so, then I have tried every item on your list twice.

Any idea what JobWriter.StartJob() does? I tried reflector, but couldn't quite grok where it gets to HandleResponse() where it throws the exception. "Unauthorized" is a rather vague error message. I assume it comes from the TFS server. Is there an audit log that could give me any useful clues?

Comment: And just to be clear, by "Build Agent Service Accounts" do you mean the collection's "Project Collection Build Service Accounts" group? (this group is not defined for my project btw, just the collection housing my project)

Comment: Yes. Try with an account in both Build Agent Service Accounts and Agent Pool Service Account.

Comment: I get the feeling that three different users are involved:
1) The user who ran the ConfigureAgent.cmd script
2) The vsoagent /login:user,password user used to override the 1) user when setting up the service
3) The windows service user running the vsoagentservice

So... normally, at the configuration stage I can specify the admin user (2) and the little script will contact my tfs server and make sure the build agent's user (presumably the service user 3) is enlisted in the relevant roles?

Comment: Check out my recent edit. If my user is not included in the service account role, then vsoagent won't even start listening (because it can't). Something else is in play here.

Comment: https? Indeed.

Yesterday we used http instead, which worked. Then we swapped back to using https and then that too worked... I would love to learn why. I will try to dig a little deeper once I have finished other build-related matters.